# How to figure out proper xpath for IMPORTXML in Google Sheets - N/A Error?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use the IMPORTXML function on Google Sheets.

For example: `=IMPORTXML("https://www.tiktok.com/@charlidamelio?lang=en", XMLPATH)` should return "54.3M"

I used the Chrome inspector to copy the xpath, which gives me:

`/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/header/h2[1]/strong[2]`

When I try this in Google Sheets it returns an error: *#N/A (Import Content is Empty).*

P.S. I'm open to other ways to get the data I need into the google sheet, it doesn't have to use the IMPORTXML function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this answer?

In this answer, `IMPORTXML` and `REGEXEXTRACT` are used. And also, it supposes that the URL of `https://www.tiktok.com/@charlidamelio?lang=en` is put in a cell "A1".

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, "followerCount" is retrieved.

#### Sample formula:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A1,"//script[@id='__NEXT_DATA__']"),"followerCount"":(\d+)")
```

- "followerCount" is retrieved from the script.
- In this case, when `=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A1,"//script[@id='__NEXT_DATA__']"),"followerCount"":(\d+)"))` is used, the retrieved value can be used as the number.

#### Result:

[image]

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, "followerCount" is retrieved.

#### Sample formula:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A1,"//meta[@name='description']/@content")," ([\w\d.]+) Fans")
```

- The value of "54.4M Fans" is retrieved from the metadata.

#### Result:

[image]

### References:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)
- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Comment: Thanks very much! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @ConfuciusCat Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I really appreciated your help before and your solution worked for over a month, however now it is not working anymore. Do you know why that may be the case? =REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A1,"//script[@id='__NEXT_DATA__']"),"followerCount"":(\d+)")

Comment: @ConfuciusCat Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63007134) was related to this. So I would like to comment to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63007134). Please check it.